# DJango URL Reverse Error: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from common.views import HomeView, LoadingSchoolView, ProcessSchoolView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='Index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^member/', include('member.urls', namespace='member')),
    url(r'^common/', include('common.urls', namespace='common')),
```

In my common/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import QuerySchoolView

urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^querySchool/(?P<q>[a-z]*)$', QuerySchoolView.as_view(), name='querySchool'),
}
```

Now, when I do

```
{% url 'common:querySchool' %},
```

It gives me a `TypeError`

```
TypeError at /member/register/learner
argument to reversed() must be a sequence
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/member/register/learner
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
argument to reversed() must be a sequence
Exception Location:       /Users/enzii/python_env/django18/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _populate, line 285
Python Executable:  /Users/enzii/python_env/django18/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.3
```

Here is My View

```
class QuerySchoolView(View):

    def get(self, request, q=""):

        universities = University.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=q) |
                                  Q(pinyin__contains=q) |
                                  Q(province__contains=q) |
                                  Q(country__contains=q))[:4]

        returnObj = [{'unvis-name': u.name, 'country': u.country, 'province': u.province} for u in  universities]

        return HttpResponse(returnObj)
```

What is wrong with my `{% url %}` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a URL called "index", you have one called "Index".

And in your common/urls, you are using `{}` instead of `[]` to wrap the patterns.

In future, please post each question separately.

Comment: but, how about the {% url 'common:querySchool' %},

Answer (score 2):

**Query-1 Solution:**

You have `Index` defined as the reverse name for the `HomePage` view  in the urls but you are using `index` as the reverse name for the url in your template.
Change `index` to `Index` and your code will work.

```
<a class="btn btn-default-ar" href="{% url 'common:Index' %}">
```

`Index` will default to application namespace i.e `common` so accessing the reversed url by `common` namespace.

You can even do the opposite that is changing the reverse name in your urls to `index` without any change in the template. It will work.

**Query-2 Solution:**

Urlpatterns defined in the urls.py file should be a **list** of patterns. As [Gocht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3945375/gocht) mentioned in the comment, try changing the urlpatterns defined in `common` app urls to a list [].

**common/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import QuerySchoolView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^querySchool/(?P<q>[a-z]*)$', QuerySchoolView.as_view(), name='querySchool'),
]
```

Comment: how about the  {% url 'common:querySchool' %}, it complains about the Type Error. why?

Comment: @EnXie that's beause you use {} intead of [] in common/urls.py

Comment: You're missing out the namespace in the URL, it should be `{% url 'common:Index' %}`

Comment: You are right. It should default to the application namespace i.e. `common`. Updated the ans.